# git check if branch can be merged

Tags: git, github, scikit-learn

I am doing pull request for the sklearn library on github:
["pull request"](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/4376#issuecomment-81866078)

One of the moderator said that there was an issue with the tracking and that was necessary to rebase. 
How did he understood that there was this problem? How can I know if the branch can now be merged?

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with python. So you shouldn't use the python tag.

Answer (score 2):

He probably attempted to merge it and encountered a conflict.

You can do so with `--no-commit` to prevent actually creating a commit, and then discard the changes.